# Malloc until sudden Termination without error

Tags: c, memory, malloc

I am trying to create a program which reads integers from a file with 103690 pairs of integers while skipping lines starting with # and saves them inside an array. Eventhough it does it successfully, it suddenly stops after a specific line (line 5115).

The file looks like this:

```
#I must
#be
#skipped
8050    6737
8050    7238
```

The code is:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

typedef struct {
    int start;
    int end;   
} path;

int doublesize(path* array,int n){
    path* new_array=malloc(n*2*sizeof(path));
    if(new_array==NULL){
        printf("Error allocating memory\n");
        abort();
    }

    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        new_array[i]=array[i];
    }
    free(array);
    array=new_array;
    n*=2;
    return n;

}


int main()
{
    int maxsize=10;
    int test;
    path* array=malloc(maxsize*sizeof(path));
    if(array==NULL) {
        printf("Error allocating memory\n");
        abort();
    }


    FILE* fd=fopen("Wiki-Vote2.txt","r");
    if(fd==NULL) {
        printf("Error opening file\n");
        abort();
    }
    char buff[200];
    int counter=0;

    char c;
    while(fgets(buff,200,fd)) {

        c=buff[0];
        if(c=='#') {
            continue;
        }
        test=sscanf(buff,"%d%d",&array[counter].start,&array[counter].end);
        printf("%d\t%d\n",array[counter].start,array[counter].end);
        printf("Read %d numbers\n", test);
        counter++;
        if(counter==maxsize){
           maxsize=doublesize(array,maxsize); 
        }


    }


    fclose(fd);
    free(array);
    return 0;
}
```

I have tried reducing the number of integers which works but when I used gdb I saw that it returned the signal `sigsegv`(I use windows).Could the memory be insufficient or is it something else?

Comment: maybe OT but why don't you use `realloc()`? That *might* prevent the system from having both parts of memory allocated during the process of reallocation, and it would be much simpler

Comment: regarding statements like: `printf("Error allocating memory\n");`  Error messages should be output to `stderr`, not `stdout` and when the error indication is from a C library function, should also output the text reason the system thinks the error occurred.  The function: `perror()` is made for this purpose.

Comment: regarding: `abort();`  this is a very poor way to exit a program. Amongst other reasons, this results in a memory leak.  Suggest: `free( array); exit( EXIT_FAILURE );`  Where both `exit()` and `EXIT_FAILURE` are exposed via the statement; `#include <stdlib.h>`

Comment: OT:  regarding: `for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        new_array[i]=array[i];
    }`   This can be greatly simplified to: `memcpy( new_array, array, n*sizeof( path ) );`

Comment: regarding: `test=sscanf(buff,"%d%d",&array[counter].start,&array[counter].end);`  This is not checking for errors.  Suggest:  `if( (test=sscanf(buff,"%d%d",&array[counter].start,&array[counter].end) ) != 2 )  { // handle error }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Function arguments are passed by value. That includes pointers. So when you do `array=new_array;` inside `doublesize` you are assigning to **a copy** of the pointer `array` pointer from `main`. The value of `array` inside `main` function stays the same.

You can pass a pointer to the pointer to change it's value.

```
int doublesize(path **array,int n){
    ...
        // first dereference array, then access element number i
        new_array[i] = (*array)[i];
    }
    // free the array where array points to, ie array in main
    free(*array);
    // assign new value to array
    *array = new_array;
    n *= 2;
    return n;
}


int main()
{
    ...
           // pass array by pointer to let doublesize modify it
           maxsize = doublesize(&array, maxsize); 
    ...
}
```

I think it could be clearer to change the `doublesize` function to return the new pointer and to take a pointer to `int` variable that represents maxsize, like so:

```
path *doublesize(path *array, int *maxsize){
    int n = *maxsize;
    ...
    free(array);
    // maxsize here points to the variable maxsize in main
    // let's write n * 2 to it
    *maxsize = n * 2;
    // return the new pointer
    return new_array;
}


int main()
{
    ...
           // array is updated with the new value
           // maxsize is updated with 
           array = doublesize(array, &maxsize); 
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in your resizing function:

```
int doublesize(path* array,int n){
     ...
     array=new_array;
```

The variable `array` is local to the function, so changes to it aren't reflected in the calling function.  As a result, `array` in `main` now points to freed memory after this function returns, and attempting to dereference that pointer invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

You should change this function to accept a `path **`:

```
int doublesize(path **array,int n){
    path *new_array=malloc(n*2*sizeof(path));
    if(new_array==NULL){
        printf("Error allocating memory\n");
        abort();
    }

    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        new_array[i]=(*array)[i];
    }
    free(*array);
    *array=new_array;
    n*=2;
    return n;

}
```

And pass the address of `array` in `main`:

```
maxsize=doublesize(&array,maxsize);
```

Answer (score 1):

In `doublesize()` you reassign `array`, but here it's only a local variable, so after the function returns, `array` in `main()` still holds the original now freed pointer. So you should pass a double pointer (and use `realloc()`) so that your function could look like that:

```
int doublesize(path** array,int n){
    path* new_array=realloc( *array, n*2*sizeof(path));
    if(new_array==NULL){
        printf("Error allocating memory\n");
        abort();
    }

    *array=new_array;
    return n*2;
}
```

Call the function by

```
maxsize=doublesize(&array,maxsize);
```